# Connect remote machines via SSH to command prompt

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell

I created an SSH connection between my machines, and then i set on one of them a PowerShell command telling windows to provide the PowerShell console when a distant machine connects to the current via SSH and that automatically and by default, (i don't remember the command i used)

Now i want to cancel that so that when i ssh to my machine it gets me to the command prompt (and not PowerShell)

Anybody knows the canceling command ?

Answer (score 0):

The usual method to configure what a user sees when they connect via SSH to an SSH server is to **set/change the "default shell"** or "default command shell".

According to the [manual](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration) in Windows that can be done with the following PowerShell command:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:c:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
```

The example above from the manual sets the default shell to be `powershell.exe`

Restore that back to the initial Windows default which is the Windows Command shell (cmd.exe)

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:c:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
```

Another method is to **leave the default shell unchanged and to configure that default shell to run a different command on start-up**. How and if that is the case depends on what your default shell is currently  set to.

For example if you configured `bash` as your default shell, then you could have modified your  .bashrc  to start  "`powershell.exe`" on login.